# Merge floppy images in Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, floppy

On my Raspberry pi I am trying to install windows 95 in dosbox. I know that it probably won't work, but I want to try. I cannot download the large CD image so I downloaded a set of 13 floppy images. The setup wizard, instead of asking me for the location of the drive that the floppy is in, prompts me to insert the floppy in the same drive, which AFAIK you can't do in Dosbox.

TL;DR I would like to know how to merge 13 floppy images into one large image that the setup wizard can read. I am running Rasbpian

Comment: `Raspberry pi + windows 95 + dosbox` ==> creepy. Anyway I would suggest to create an ISO file instead of a big cd and mount this iso I think it could still work.

Comment: Can't you just mount each image one after the other in the same location?

Comment: The floppy setup is designed to ask for disk1-disk13, you'll break the setup if you try to cat the 13 into 1. As kiwy suggested, dl the CD image and mount the iso. The iso can be store elsewhere and mounted via samba or nfs.

Comment: @terdon I can't get a dosbox DOS prompt up at the same time as win95 setup wizard, but thanks!

Comment: It is not storage space but download time I am worrying about, so I need a solution that does not involve downloading the CD image.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, the contents of disks 2-13 are entirely package (`.cab`) files. Disk 1 will have some cab files as well, but it's mostly the OS kernel and installer program.

What I would do is try to expand the size of disk 1 (possibly using gparted?), then copy the `.cab` files from each of disks 2-13 into the newly embiggened disk 1.

I believe there is also an index file on disk 1 that lists each cab file and which disk it's on. You'll want to find that and set them all to disk 1.

Good luck, and may the Force be with you.

Comment: There are only 2 text files in disk 1: INSTALL.TXT and README.TXT. These are all human readable text and contain no settings. Would I need to use a hex editor to alter some of the binaries? And how do I get gparted to recognise a virtual drive?